# Tableview select row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

I have a tableview which contains images in cell.

If I touch an image in any row of the table,it should redirect to the nextpage and show that perticular image in next page.

Please help me figure how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ***didSelectRowAtIndexPath*** delegate:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

by knowing which `UITableviewCell` got selected using `[indexPath row]` you will get what you need, let's assume you're storing your `UIImages` in an array `MyImagesArray`

```
UIImage* MySelectedImage = [MyImagesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

---

*This is an another Answer for **Comment #3** on this Answer:*

Declare a variable in the `UIViewController` that is going to show the image and pass the selected image, or you can even send the name of the `UIImage`:

```
 ImageViewer* oImageViewer = [[ImageVieweralloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewer" bundle:nil];

 // Assume MyImagesArray contains the images names.
 oImageViewer.sSelectedImageName = [MyImagesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:oImageViewer animated:YES];
```

In ImageViewer load the image by it's name for example:

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.sSelectedImageName];
```

Comment: @Ahamad can you expline in detail??i have 5 images in 5 rows,if i selct first row it will redirct to next page and show that image..

Comment: @Nipin pn: cool, are you using `UINavigationController` and you want to push new Controller? or you want to add new `UIView`?

Comment: i am using UINavigationController ,i want to push it to nextview and display that corresponding image,,i knew how to push from oneview to another,but dontknow how to pass an image

Comment: @Ahamad i am using UINavigationController ,i want to push it to nextview and display that corresponding image,,i knew how to push from oneview to another,but dontknow how to pass an image